# how to add quotes to a search string for an exact match?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code here for a song request program. And it works just fine other than the user has to use surrounding quotes for an exact match. I am wondering how I would go about having the php add the quotes so the user can type a band or song title as normal without having to read the small help notice saying to use quotes?

Comment: `$str = '"' . $value_from_user . '"';`

Comment: String manipulation is a fundamental aspect of php

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AstLwRmW is the php for the main part I am trying to alter to do only exact match searching rather than matching each word individually as it is typed. http://pastebin.com/uZEimSsy is the required class that goes with it. The company that made this has it so scattered it is hard to make sense of what to alter. I tried from the comment below about replacing "like" with "=" and that returns zero matches each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can concate quotes in after if you like.

```
$termToSearch = '"' . $termFromUser . '"';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE song = :song'
$statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':song', $termToSearch);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man that worked just fine when I altered the variable. man it was killing me.

Comment: Awesome - dont forget to vote a correct answer for future people searching the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Just use "=" instead of "LIKE"

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$searchterm'
```